# Apache Airflow scheduler is not running after some time

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am running a complex flow in apache airflow and using local executor with postgres db. It is running for tasks and scheduler goes down after some time. In airlfow console cant see any logs

using airflow - puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9 deployed in openshift environment

Error in airflow UI:
***The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 3 hours ago.
The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.***

Comment: Are you sure you correctly configured the Postgres database? What is your sql_alchemy_conn set too?

Comment: As a side note: the KubernetesExecutor will be a lot more stable if you are running on OpenShift anyway. LocalExecutor really isn't great for production environments.

Comment: @Blokje5, postgres is configured properly. after triggering the DAG, some tasks are running as expected . After running few taks, scheduler goes down. I I increased the dag_concurrency, max_threads and all related properties. still issue exists

Comment: So then it seems the sqlite issue is a red herring, Could you include the scheduler logs in the post?

Comment: There must be some logs, can you check webserver logs? Can you also shift to CeleryExecutor since you already have local executor running. Did you modify the `puckel` image in anyway? if yes, it will be better to post it.

Comment: {{scheduler_job.py:165}} ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2276, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()   ..................
     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "DB_server_name" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: above is the scheduler logs